# List<string> and string[] WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have created a WCF service and exposed a function which accept List as a parameter.

```
public bool Execute(string databaseServer, string database, string ClientName, string ERAPayerID, string PlanPriority, List<string> AdjCode, List<string> RemarkCode, List<string> CPT, string Modifier, string renderingProviderNPI)
```

when I call this function it ask me to provide string[] instead of 
List

```
WriteOffServiceClient client = new WriteOffServiceClient();
bool resutl = client.Execute("server", "database", practiseIdentifier, "", ERAPayerId, pPriority, new List<string>, new List<string>, new List<string>, "", "");
```

it gives me this error of invalid arguments.When I call it with string it accept it.

```
WriteOffServiceClient client = new WriteOffServiceClient();
bool resutl = client.Execute("server", "database", practiseIdentifier, "", ERAPayerId, pPriority, new string[5], new string[5], new string[5], "", "");
```

What do I do If I want to accept only List?

Comment: Why would you want to accept a List anyway? over 90% of the cases you only need to do a `foreach` on the argument, so an `IEnumerable<T>` is all you need.

Comment: Because I have some logic on service side which decides based on .isGenericType==true or false.

Comment: A `List<T>` is no more generic than an `IEnumerable<T>`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is relevant to how you added the service reference. You can choose the collection type while add the service reference.

**Add Service Reference -> Input your Url and with Advanced button** you can select `System.Collection.Generic.List` for collection option.

Comment: perfect! worked like a charm thanks